# SQL query to make value monotonic?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a data table - a *large* one, with electricity consumption values.

Sometimes, due to a glitch, the value is smaller than the previous record, which then causes problems when processing.

```
monday    143 kWh
tuesday   140 kWh *glitch*
wednesday 150 kWh
```

I'd like to make the table monotonic. I'm interested in finding out if there is an sql query that will set each glitched value to the previous greatest value.

Is this possible to do without PHP?

The table is in the following format (when simplified a bit):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `history` (
  `day` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` float NOT NULL
)
```

I know how to do it in PHP, row by row, but if there's a cleaner SQL-only solution, that'd be superb!

Comment: I don't think you understand the meaning of the word **monotonous** as your question shouldn't be using it.

Comment: I imagine he means `monotonic`, @Styphon.

Comment: Perhaps it was the Tuesday in the week before: why not actually store a date?

Comment: @pjd You're probably right, I haven't heard of monotonic before  :). Nice word.

Comment: *Glitch*?!?! you do know that electric monitors can run backwards if the home provides electricity to the grid instead of receiving it right? (Like if they have a generator, or solar power tied in and use less than is being generated)

Comment: So the word is monotonic? idk I translated it without checking any reference. I mean always equal or greater than before

Comment: I know that @xQbert, but there's a bit more going on, this is actually a "difference" meter that logs difference between value from master, and one of it's "branch" meters. So it should be positive.

Comment: The problem is that I have a rather large data collected already which I need to fix, for future data I can just clamp it to the previous value.

Comment: @MightyPork monotonous means boring, repetitive work. I'm guessing that's why it came up in the translation.

Comment: yeah, in czech it's "monotonní" (which means both "boring" and "monotonic" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the sequence to be "monotonic".  "Monotonous" means boring.

If you have a lot of data, then the most efficient way is using variables:

```
select h.day,
       (@max := greatest(@max, h.value)
from history h cross join
     (select @max := -1) params
order by h.day;
```

If you actually want to *update* the values, then you can do basically the same thing:

```
update history h
    set value = (@max := greatest(coalesce(@max + 0, 0), h.value)
    order by h.day;
```

Note that in this case, `@max` defaults to a string variable.  You cannot have both an `order by` and `join` in a an `update` query.  So, either define the variable just before the `update`, or do a bit of string-to-number conversion.

Comment: Could you please explain how this works? it's a prod database and I'd really not like to screw it up by running something I don't understand.

Comment: @MightPork . . . The first query just queries the table and returns the values that you want.  The second actually makes changes.  However, I might suggest that you save the results of the first query in a table, validate them.  Then truncate the other table and reload the data from the first table.

Comment: Ok it does not really work for float values, but it worked ok for integers... weird

Comment: @MightyPork . . . Are you sure the float values are stored as numbers and not strings?